# Is Underwater hair simulation possible

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, hair

Is it possible to make underwater hair simulation?

I haven't tried it yet, but is it possible for hair particles to react to water particles?

Comment: This question would benefit a lot from more specifics about the particular effect you are trying to achieve, e.g. sample pictures, screenshots/settings for what you have tried so far.

Comment: If you want fully underwater motion, I'd start with increasing the air drag settings as water is thicker, and reducing gravity to approximate buoyancy and see what that looks like. Transitioning between underwater/above water is much harder.